# How determine the method of moments to this "quasi-Rayleigh" distribution?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I'm trying to find some estimators to this P.D.F. $$f(x|\theta) = \frac{x}{\theta} exp\left \{ \frac{-x^{2}}{2\theta} \right \}, x \geq 0, \theta\geq 0$$ I already got the MLE! But how can I determine the method of moments, taking in consideration that this P.D.F. is a "quasi-Rayleigh" distribution?

Comment: It is a Rayleigh distribution, though $\theta$ is the square of the scale.  What is its mean in terms of $\theta$?  What is $\theta$ in terms of its mean?

Comment: There may be more than one method of moments estimator: I suspect that the MLE you say you found may be *a* method of moments estimator (it uses the second moment about $0$ rather than the first moment) though possibly not the one you are looking for.